# Removing everything after `*`

Tags: regex, r, substring

I was wondering how to remove everything after a `*` in my data. I have values such as: `IGHV4-59*01` and `IGHV4-4*02` and wanted just the `IGHV4-59` and `IGHV-4`. I tried using the sub but did not get the desired result:

```
sub("*.*" , " ", data_head$v_segment)
## [1] " " " " " " " " " " " "
```

Instead of removing everything after the * it removed everything entirely. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Basically, `*` is a metacharacter in regex, and thus you need to escape it if you want to the engine to treat it as an actual punctuation character.

```
gsub("\\*.*", "", c("IGHV4-59*01", "IGHV4-4*02")) # You can use `sub` too as per comment
## [1] "IGHV4-59" "IGHV4-4"
```

Comment: This doesn't really make a difference, but `gsub` is completely unnecessary here since the pattern will already match everything after the _first_ occurrence of `"*"`.

Comment: What do you mean by "completely unnecessary"? Do you mean that I can use `sub` instead? I could agree, but I think you a bit harsh both in your comment and in the posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex failed because `*` is a special character in a regular expression even when there is no other character in front of it. Therefore it needs to be escaped. `"\\*.*"` is the pattern you want.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work as expected because you need to escape `*` to match a literal.

```
sub("\\*.*", "", data_head$v_segment)
```